# How to call a function with less arguments that is set (Python 3)

Tags: function, python-3.x, terminal, arguments, emulation

I am making a terminal emulator in Python 3. The commands are being stored in functions, like:

```
def rd(os_vartmp, os_vartmp2):
    if os_vartmp == None:
        print('rd [path] [-S]')
        print('Delete a folder')
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(os_vartmp) == True:
            if os_vartmp2 == '-S': print('a')
            else:
                print(ERR5)

a = input('Command: ')
```

The terminal works like this:

1. Asks user for input
2. Splits the input
3. Uses the first part of input to search a function in locals
4. If there is one, uses the rest part of input as argument
5. Calls the function

The thing here is, when i call the function 'rd' with, for example, 'rd "boot.py" -S' it works just fine. But if i need to call it like this: rd "boot.py", it throws me a error about 1 argument given when 2 are required. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Have the function accept an arbitrary number of parameters with [`def rd(os_vartmp, *args)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

You can make an argument optional by assigning a value in the method definition. For example:

```
def Add(x=0, y=0):
    return x+y
```

If you input only one value, y will default to 0. If I wanted to give y a value but have x fall back on it's default value I could do `Add(y=10)`. I hope this helped!

Comment: That didnt work for me, because it seems that i cant change the value of os_vartmp2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
def rd(os_vartmp, os_vartmp2="-S"):
```

Instead of trying to get null value, which would require rd("boot.py",null), you can ser default value and then you can do rd("boot.py").

Hope it works.

Comment: But sometimes i dont need '-S'

Comment: Is there another thing you may put as default value? Perhaps def rd(os_vartmp, os_vartmp2=""): Thought, not sure if it will work,

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but it seems that i cant change os_vartmp2 value. If i call it with '-S', it sets os_vartmp2 as ""